# Update MongoDB ReferenceField using Flask-Admin

Tags: python, mongodb, flask-admin

I'm trying to create an admin page from which I can edit what roles a user is member of using MonogDB and Flask-Admin.

**models.py**

```py
class Role(db.Document, RoleMixin):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    description = db.StringField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    email = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    roles = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(Role))
```

**admin.py**

```py
class UserView(ModelView):
    from wtforms.fields import SelectMultipleField
    from bson import ObjectId, DBRef
    form_overrides = dict(roles=SelectMultipleField)
    options = [(g.id, g.name) for g in models.Role.objects()]
    # print options
    # [(ObjectId('54a72849426c702850d01921'), u'community'),
    #  (ObjectId('54a72849426c702850d01922'), u'customer')]
    form_args = dict(roles=dict(choices=options))
```

When I select a user role in the Flask-Admin edit_form view and cilck save, following form validation error is shown: **'54a72849426c702850d01922' is not a valid choice for this field**

What's the correct way to edit/update a ReferenceField ?

Answer (score 0):

Your models look fine. But your `ModelView` is the problem. I'm using MongoEngine and here is my implementation for them.

```
class Role(db.Document, RoleMixin):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    description = db.StringField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    email = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=500)
    active = db.BooleanField(default=True)
    confirmed_at = db.DateTimeField()
    roles = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(Role), default=[])

    # Optional to override save method.
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = encrypt_password(self.password) # You can encrypt your password before storing in db, as a good practice.
        self.confirmed_at = datetime.now()

        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here are my model view:

```
class UserView(ModelView):
    can_create = True
    can_delete = True
    can_edit = True
    decorators = [login_required]

    column_filters = ('email',)

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.has_role("admin")

class RoleView(ModelView):
    can_create = True
    can_delete = True
    can_edit = True
    decorators = [login_required]

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.has_role("admin")
```

You don't have to get all Roles objects explicitly, `flask-admin` would do it for you. You just have to create Roles first before creating User Object.

Also, you can create an initial user by using flask's `before_first_request` like this:

```
@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
    user_datastore.find_or_create_role(name='admin', description='Administrator')
    encrypted_password = encrypt_password('password') # Put in your password here
    if not user_datastore.get_user('user@example.com'):
        user_datastore.create_user(email='user@example.com', password=encrypted_password)
        user_datastore.add_role_to_user('user@example.com', 'admin')
```

This would help you in updating references correctly.